# How to get the difference in years from two different dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the difference in years from two different dates using MySQL database.

for example:

- 2011-07-20 - 2011-07-18 => 0 year
- 2011-07-20 - 2010-07-20 => 1 year
- 2011-06-15 - 2008-04-11 => <strike>2</strike> 3 years
- 2011-06-11 - 2001-10-11 => 9 years

How about the SQL syntax? Is there any built in function from MySQL to produce the result?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here's the expression that also caters for leap years:

```
YEAR(date1) - YEAR(date2) - (DATE_FORMAT(date1, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(date2, '%m%d'))
```

This works because the expression `(DATE_FORMAT(date1, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(date2, '%m%d'))` is `true` if date1 is "earlier in the year" than date2 *and* because in mysql, `true = 1` and `false = 0`, so the adjustment is simply a matter of subtracting the "truth" of the comparison.

This gives the correct values for your test cases, except for test #3 - I think it should be "3" to be consistent with test #1:

```
create table so7749639 (date1 date, date2 date);
insert into so7749639 values
('2011-07-20', '2011-07-18'),
('2011-07-20', '2010-07-20'),
('2011-06-15', '2008-04-11'),
('2011-06-11', '2001-10-11'),
('2007-07-20', '2004-07-20');
select date1, date2,
YEAR(date1) - YEAR(date2)
    - (DATE_FORMAT(date1, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(date2, '%m%d')) as diff_years
from so7749639;
```

Output:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| date1      | date2      | diff_years |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 2011-07-20 | 2011-07-18 |          0 |
| 2011-07-20 | 2010-07-20 |          1 |
| 2011-06-15 | 2008-04-11 |          3 |
| 2011-06-11 | 2001-10-11 |          9 |
| 2007-07-20 | 2004-07-20 |          3 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ae42/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. And For the #3 test case it should be 3 years. I have another test case (leap year): 2007-07-20 - 2004-07-20 => 3 years but the result still 2 years.

Comment: @aslingga No problem. I have improved the solution so it is now correct for all your tests, including leap year issue.

Comment: Hey i am able to achieve above result but my condition is that i need 0.5 year , 1 year, 1.5 year, 2 year ,2.5 year and so on.. how could i do that!!

Comment: @dipen that is a different question, so ask a new question. Also, this solution can't be adapted to return fractions of years.

Answer (score 33):

I like the solution by Bohemian, but what about using [timestampdiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
select date1, date2,timestampdiff(YEAR,date2,date1) from so7749639
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ae42/12/0)

just seems easier.

Comment: this is the best/easiest answer.

Answer (score 14):

Simply by: `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date1, date2) AS difference FROM table`.

Answer (score 12):

```
mysql> SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF('2011-06-11','2001-10-11')/365);
+------------------------------------------------+
| FLOOR(DATEDIFF('2011-06-11','2001-10-11')/365) |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                              9 |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

[DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) returns difference in days between two dates. This does not specifically take leap years into account but it may work in such cases:

```
mysql> SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF('2007-07-11','2004-07-11')/365);
+------------------------------------------------+
| FLOOR(DATEDIFF('2007-07-11','2004-07-11')/365) |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                              3 |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Enquirer dosn't mention them at all so I assume he does not care.

Comment: sorry because I forgot to add a test case for leap year.

Answer (score 2):

you could just use

```
SELECT ROUND((TO_DAYS(date2) - TO_DAYS(date1)) / 365) ...
```

Also wrap it with `ABS()` if you want always a positive number, no matter which date precedes the other.

With `ROUND()`, 0.6 years will be considered 1 year, if instead you want to count only the full years, you can use `FLOOR()`. In this case 0.6 year will be considered 0 years, and 1.9 years will be considered 1 year.

Comment: it should be TO_DAYS both times. I cannot edit it as edits must be >=6 symbols. please correct

Answer (score 0):

Number of years between date1 and date2:

```
IF((YEAR(date2) - YEAR(date1)) > 0, (YEAR(date2) - YEAR(date1)) - (MID(date2, 6, 5) < 
MID(date1, 6, 5)), IF((YEAR(date2) - YEAR(date1)) < 0, (YEAR(date2) - YEAR(date1)) + 
(MID(date1, 6, 5) < MID(date2, 6, 5)), (YEAR(date2) - YEAR(date1))))
```

Now for some comments about these.

1. These results return integer number of years, months, and days. They are "floored." Thus, 1.4 days would display as 1 day, and 13.9 years would display as 13 years. Likewise, -1.4 years would display as -1 year, and -13.9 months would display as -13 months.
2. Note that I use boolean expressions in many cases. Because boolean expressions evaluate to 0 or 1, I can use them to subtract or add 1 from the total based on a condition.

Answer (score 0):

This works well, even taking in account for leap years:

```
select floor((cast(date_format('2016-02-14','%Y%m%d') as int) - cast(date_format('1966-02-15','%Y%m%d') as int)/10000);
```

Keep the floor as a decimal will be incorrect most of the time.