# Error in selecting age in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm trying to get the difference in years with MySQL but it is showing an error when selecting the same.

```
SELECT(
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT('birthdate', '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT('birthdate', '00-%m-%d')) AS age
) FROM register where 'reg_id' = user254
```

What is the error?

Comment: I'll ask you this. What's the error generated? What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: It's very nice of you to tell us what the error is. How is anyone supposed to help you when you give barely any information about your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
SELECT (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthdate)) AS age) 
FROM register 
WHERE reg_id = 'user254'
```

Or (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates))

```
SELECT (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthdate) - 
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%m%d'))) AS age 
FROM register
WHERE reg_id = 'user254'
```

Comment: Guessing `where reg_id = 'user254'`.

Comment: also one problem is apart you corrected '' part the brace before as `) AS` this will be removed, thanks for help you did good reply!

Answer (score 3):

Just substracting the years does not actually give you the age - it will be as if everyone was born on january 1st. Try just doing a datediff:

```
SELECT FLOOR((DATEDIFF(NOW(),birthdate))/365)
FROM register 
WHERE reg_id = 'user254'
```

Remember: put quotes around literal values (like 'user254' or 'John'), but no regular quotes around table names or column names! You will want to use backtikcs (`) for those.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ( YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthdate) - 
(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%m%d'))
AS age) FROM register WHERE 'reg_id' = user254
```

Comment: If you are going to copy other people's answers, atleast credit!