# Finding age using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine I have a field DOB which stores date of birth of an employee.

Is there a query to find out the **AGE** of the employees?

The output that I want is

```
EmpNo     Age
1          30
```

I am using MySQL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates use `now()` or `curdate()` as the second mysql docs also cover it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html

Comment: I need the calculation to be done for each employee record and display the age next to the employee number. I have shown my intent in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is year and are not worried about months

`SELECT EmpNo, DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOBFIELD, GETDATE()) As Age From Table`

Sorry I gave the MSSQL version

Try

`SELECT EmpNo, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(GETDATE(),DOBFIELD)/365) Age From Table`

Comment: This error is shown `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'`

Comment: This query worked `SELECT `eno` , TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, `dob` , CURDATE( ) ) AS age
FROM `employee``

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF(day,DOB,GETDATE())/365.242199)

It's best if you put this into a function. Hope this helps.