# How to update thousands of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to update an age column based on the value in a date of birth column. There are thousands of records to update.

How do I do this using rails?

Is this the right way to do it?

```
User.update_all(:age => some_method);

def some_method
  age = Date.today.year - dob.year
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `update_all` is the right method but no, you can't do it like this. Your `some_method` will only get called once to set up a database call (I assume you're persisting to a database). You'll then get an error because `dob` won't be recognised in the scope of the `User` class.

You'll need to translate your date logic to SQL functions.

Something like (for mysql):

```
User.update_all("age = year(now()) - 
                year(dob) - 
                (DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m%d'))")
```

(NB. the date_format stuff is so that you get the right age for people who's birthdays are later in the year than the current date - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates) for more details)

Comment: its is not if there are callbacks to trigger

Comment: Good point. If there's other logic hanging off this then you'll need to iterate through the users. Make sure you do it in batches though.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use one of the batches functionality in rails.

```
User.where(some_condition).find_in_batches do |group_of_users|
 # some logic
 # e.g. group_of_users.update_all(:age => some_logic)
end
```

This would lock your db for less time. Note that you should pretty much always update with a condition in mind. I can't think of many cases you would want to update an entire table every time something happens.

There are a few options checkout the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches) or the [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html).

Answer (score 0):

your query is right.

There are many way to update record in a batch/lot.

But, I think that your query is best. Because it is rails query that will support every condition for all database.

for updating more than one attributes

```
Model.update_all(:column1 => value1, :column2 => value2, ........)
```

or

you can use :

```
Model.update_all("column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ........")
```