# How to convert a date of birth into an age and save it into a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a online record for our family members.

I have two tables Member and MemberDetails, and the BirthDate is inserted in the 'member' table. I want to calculate age using this BirthDate stored in table 'Member' and store it in table MemberDetails for each member under the column 'Age'.

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates). In this example your date2 will be current date.

Comment: There's usually no point in taking a stored date of birth and converting it to an age to store, as it provides a way for discrepancy to leak into the database (and ages need to be recalculated anyway). Why not calculate the age in real-time when you need it?

Comment: Thanks halfer, but i need the age calculated to sort the members into different age groups. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this directly in SQL,

Try something like

```
INSERT INTO Member_Detail (id, dob)
VALUES SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) FROM Member
```

Comment: This will update all members. This should run done daily (to ensure current ages), as well as whenever a member is added. Ideally this would use a date of death in place of current date if not null.

Comment: Thank you Kami , seems like this will solve my query.

Comment: Paul, Thank you for the advice, i am planning on running the query via phpmyadmin once and then write a query in the insert member page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<?php
$birthDate = "05-03-1991";  // m-d-Y
$birthDate = explode("-", $birthDate);

$age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], $birthDate[2]))) > date("md")
? ((date("Y") - $birthDate[2]) - 1)
: (date("Y") - $birthDate[2]));

echo "Your age is:" . $age;
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:-

```
<?php
  //date in mm/dd/yyyy format; or it can be in other formats as well
  $birthDate = "12/17/1983";
  //explode the date to get month, day and year
  $birthDate = explode("/", $birthDate);
  //get age from date or birthdate
  $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], $birthDate[2]))) > date("md")
    ? ((date("Y") - $birthDate[2]) - 1)
    : (date("Y") - $birthDate[2]));
  echo "Age is:" . $age;
?>
```

or refer this link
[PHP calculate age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age)