# Select by age and gender

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made the following query to select persons by age group, as count and as percentage. Ages are stored as `0000-00-00` in my database.

```
SELECT  AgeGroup, count(*) AS count, ROUND(sum( 100 ) / total) AS percentage
        FROM    (
        SELECT  case
                when  age between 0 and 17 then '00 - 17'
                when  age between 18 and 24 then '18 − 24'
                when  age between 25 and 34 then '25 − 34'
                when  age between 35 and 44 then '35 − 44'
                when  age between 45 and 54 then '45 − 54'
                when  age between 55 and 64 then '55 − 64'
                when  age between 65 and 125 then '65+'
                else 'Unknown'
                end AS AgeGroup
        FROM    (
                SELECT  ROUND(DATEDIFF(Cast(NOW() as Date),
                            Cast(dateofbirth as Date)) / 365, 0) as age
                FROM    people
                ) as SubQueryAlias
        ) as SubQueryAlias2
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT count( * ) AS total FROM people)x
        group by
        AgeGroup
```

The current result is:

```
AgeGroup | count | percentage
00 - 17    33      1
18 − 24    235     5
..         ..      ..
```

What I need is a addition to the query to separate the results in male/female/unknown:

```
AgeGroup  | gender | count | percentage
00 - 17     M        33      1
00 - 17     F        33      1
..          ..       ..      ..
```

Comment: What result do you have with simply adding gender to your `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: use GROUP BY gender to return results in order?

Comment: @user2071225 the Group BY gender does not work for some reason

Comment: Are you using `group by AgeGroup, Gender` ?

Comment: @user2071225 yes, the column name is 'gender', but I keep receiving: Unknown column 'Gender' in 'group statement'

Comment: That suggests it should be lowercase then? if it's called 'gender' but you're getting error unknown column 'Gender'

Comment: @user2071225 in both cases the same error

Comment: SubQueryAlias2.Gender, SubQueryAlias.AgeGroup? Or the other way round

Comment: @user2071225 thank, already tried that without result

Comment: You may be interested in this for calculating ages . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hope I am wrong about it ....but would the reason of constant error be...you didn't select the gender?

Also, a nerdy side note, 365 days doesn't make a year, it's roughly 365.25 days XD which mean your equation is slightly off haha

```
SELECT  AgeGroup, gender, count(*) AS count, ROUND(sum( 100 ) / total) AS percentage
    FROM    (
    SELECT  case
            when  age between 0 and 17 then '00 - 17'
            when  age between 18 and 24 then '18 − 24'
            when  age between 25 and 34 then '25 − 34'
            when  age between 35 and 44 then '35 − 44'
            when  age between 45 and 54 then '45 − 54'
            when  age between 55 and 64 then '55 − 64'
            when  age between 65 and 125 then '65+'
            else 'Unknown'
            end AS AgeGroup, gender
    FROM    (
            SELECT  ROUND(DATEDIFF(Cast(NOW() as Date),
                        Cast(dateofbirth as Date)) / 365, 0) as age, 
                        gender
            FROM    people
            ) as SubQueryAlias
    ) as SubQueryAlias2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT count( * ) AS total FROM people)x
    group by
    AgeGroup, gender
```

Comment: you also need to select gender in `SubQueryAlias2`

Comment: ...didn't even look at that haha

Answer (score 1):

You might have the easiest time by defining range-tables.  This also prevents you from needing to do date math on every entry, and so may be more efficient for the grouping.

First, a range table for ages:

```
SELECT '00 - 17' AS ageGroup, CURRENT_DATE AS lower, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 18 YEAR AS upper
UNION ALL
SELECT '18 - 24', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 18 YEAR, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 25 YEAR
UNION ALL
SELECT '25 - 34', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 25 YEAR, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 35 YEAR
UNION ALL
SELECT '35 - 44', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 35 YEAR, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 45 YEAR
UNION ALL
SELECT '45 - 54', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 45 YEAR, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 55 YEAR
UNION ALL
SELECT '55 - 64', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 55 YEAR, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 65 YEAR
UNION ALL
SELECT '65+', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 65 YEAR, null
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Unknown', null, null
```

<kbd>[SQL FIddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/41566/0)</kbd>

...which generates a table about like you'd expect.  Note that the upper-bound is exclusive, which is why it uses the same value as the lower bound of the next row.  Note also that 1) the `'65+'` bracket has no upper bound, and 2) the `'Unknown'` bracket has neither.

Of course, we also need a `Gender` table:

```
SELECT 'M' AS gender
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Unknown'
```

(As a side note, I'd normally be using a multi-line `VALUES(...)` statements, but SQL Fiddle seems to dislike the syntax in subqueries for MySQL for some reason.  Use whichever you're comfortable with.)

There's one last piece of knowledge we need:
Specifically, `COUNT(<expression>)` will ignore `null` rows.  We can thus stitch together the full query similarly to:

```
SELECT AgeRange.ageGroup, Gender.gender, 
       COUNT(People.id), ROUND(100 * COUNT(People.id) / Total.countOfPeople) AS percentage
FROM (SELECT '00 - 17' AS ageGroup, CURRENT_DATE AS lower, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 18 YEAR AS upper
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '18 - 24', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 18 YEAR, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 25 YEAR
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '25 - 34', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 25 YEAR, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 35 YEAR
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '35 - 44', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 35 YEAR, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 45 YEAR
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '45 - 54', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 45 YEAR, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 55 YEAR
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '55 - 64', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 55 YEAR, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 65 YEAR
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '65+', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 65 YEAR, null
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Unknown', null, null)  AgeRange
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'M' AS Gender
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'F'
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT 'Unknown') Gender
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) countOfPeople
            FROM People) Total
LEFT JOIN People
       ON ((People.dateOfBirth > AgeRange.upper AND dateOfBirth <= AgeRange.lower)
           OR (People.dateOfBirth <= AgeRange.lower AND AgeRange.upper IS NULL)
           OR (AgeRange.lower IS NULL AND AgeRange.upper IS NULL AND People.dateOfBirth IS NULL))
          AND (Gender.gender = People.gender
               OR Gender.gender = 'Unknown' AND People.gender IS NULL)
GROUP BY AgeRange.ageGroup, Gender.gender
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1ea0/7/0)</kbd>
(note the Fiddle demo uses the date of this post, `'2014-07-21'`, as `CURRENT_DATE`, to make the age range query stable for future readers).