# Subtract table value from today's date - SQL

Tags: sql, subtraction, getdate

I am trying to return the number of years someone has been a part of our team based on their join date. However i am getting a invalid minus operation error. The whole `getdate()` is not my friend so i am sure my syntax is wrong.

Can anyone lend some help?

```
SELECT 
  Profile.ID as 'ID', 
  dateadd(year, -profile.JOIN_DATE, getdate()) as 'Years with Org'
FROM  Profile
```

Comment: You probably want `DATE_SUB` also is this MSSQL or MYSQL? I don't recall DATEADD being a function in MYSQL

Comment: `DATE_ADD` IS a function in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MySQL Solution**

Use the `DATE_DIFF` function

> The DATEDIFF() function returns the time between two dates.
>
> DATEDIFF(date1,date2)

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

This method only takes the number of days difference. You need to convert to years by dividing by 365. To return an integer, use the `FLOOR` method.

In your case, it would look like this

```
SELECT 
  Profile.ID as 'ID', 
  (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(profile.JOIN_DATE, getdate()) / 365)) * -1 as 'Years with Org'
FROM  Profile
```

Here's an example fiddle I created

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dbb6/2/0

**MsSQL / SQL Server solution**

> The DATEDIFF() function returns the time between two dates.
>
> Syntax: DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)

It's important to note here, that unlike it's `MySql` counterpart, the SQL Server version takes in three parameters. For your example, the code looks as follows

```
SELECT Profile.ID as 'ID', 
       DATEDIFF(YEAR,Profile.JoinDate,GETDATE()) as difference
FROM Profile
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

Comment: Is there a way to make that calculation down to the day ? For example of someone joined 6/1/2010 and today is 5/1/2016 it should return a 5. After or on 6/1/2016, it should return 6.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using T-SQL?  If so, you should use DATEDIFF:

```
DATEDIFF(year, profile.JOIN_DATE, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates), you can get your result with the following query :

```
SELECT 
  Profile.ID as 'ID', 
  YEAR(getdate()) - YEAR(profile.JOIN_DATE) - (DATE_FORMAT(getdate(), '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(profile.JOIN_DATE, '%m%d')) as 'Years with Org'
FROM  Profile
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is MS SQL:

```
    SELECT 
    Profile.ID as 'ID', 
    DATEDIFF(YEAR,Profile.JoinDate,GETDATE())
    FROM  Profile
```