# I need help putting a clause into making this statement find medianAge

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a FLOOR clause in my code to convert this piece of code from a function in which uses a bdate column to workout the age of every employee to finding the median age in the table.

```
DELIMITER \\
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getAge;
CREATE FUNCTION getAge(pdate DATE) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE years INT;
DECLARE months INT;
DECLARE days INT;
DECLARE age INT;

SELECT YEAR(pdate) INTO years;
SELECT MONTH(pdate) INTO months;
SELECT DAY(pdate) INTO days;

IF ( MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) > months ) THEN
SELECT ( YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(pdate) ) INTO age;
ELSEIF ( MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) < months ) THEN
SELECT ( ( YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(pdate) ) -1 ) INTO age;
ELSE
IF ( DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) >= DAY(pdate) ) THEN
SELECT ( YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(pdate) ) INTO age;
ELSE
SELECT ( ( YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(pdate) ) -1 ) INTO age;
END IF;
END IF;

RETURN age;
END \\
DELIMITER ;

SELECT getAge(bdate)
FROM employee
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference in years from two different dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates)

Comment: I need the median age in the already worked out ages for employees. so the median age in like 40 ages.

Comment: So then have a look at [Simple way to calculate median with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql). Fun fact: you can calculate the median birthdate (which will be faster than calculating the median from the age as a result of your function; and it could also be precalculated until you get new employees or fire someone), and then calculate the current age for that birthday.