# MySQL - How to get days between two dates as year?

Tags: mysql, date, datediff

My data:

```
birth_date
2018-07-18 12:36:35
```

So when I run the query below to get the years from user birth_date till now

```
select *, YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birth_date) as birth_year from `users`
```

it returns 1. That's right. But when I change the date from `2018-07-18` to `2018-07-19` what I want it to return is 0 because the user want 1 more day to get 1.
So I wanted to calculate it as 365 days instead of 1 year but some years are leap years. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge it did what I wanted :) and sorry for possible duplication :)