# DBMS: In this table how to display information of those employees who have more than 20 years of experience?

Tags: sql, database

[image: This] is the table I want to display information of employees who have more than 20 years of experience.

i need query for this

Comment: This is a basic `WHERE` condition.  What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference in years from two different dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates)

Comment: We don't know what information you have . and do you mean in current role or from when onboarded or in a specific skill , Question needs clarity.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which database you are using, but in oracle database, this will work fine.

```sql
select *
from Your_Table
where months_between (sysdate, Your_Employee_Hire_Date_Column) > 12 * 20
;
```